# how to send JSON data in a GET api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

I have an GET api that gets inputs in json. when I'm testing the request in insomnia that works well but after testing I generate the jquery code from insomnia and paste it in the chrome console. this is the code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "tags": [
    100
  ]
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/panel-api-backend/public/api/foods");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

xhr.send(data);
```

when I get the response, seems that input (`tags` field) isn't sent by api. when I change the request verb to `POST`. everything is ok. is there any reason that javascript can't send JSON input to APIs?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`?

Comment: doesn't work with jquery too @Andreas

Comment: `.send( data )` means you want to send data as the body of the request. But most servers do not handle a request body in GET requests, since the spec states GET requests return the resource described by the URL, the body being irrelevant. So if you need to send data with the request, you can't use GET ( Use POST instead ) or you have to send the data in the URL, as a query string, as shown in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

you can send data to GET request with `QueryString`

```
var tags=[100,200];

$.ajax({
      url:`yoururl?tags=${tags}`,
      type:'GET',
      success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
      },
      error:function(err){

      }
    });
```

you can also send like this :

```
var tags=JSON.stringify({"tags":[100,200]});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to @Shilly. GET requests doesn't have body. so it's not possible to send JSON data by the way we send them in a POST request. solution simple json inputs like an array is to put them the request query like this:

```
http://siteurl.com/api-get?arr[]=value1&arr[]=value2
```